# Insert into table ultil i < 18000

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When executing an insert query that should populate the table while i < 1800 the following error is returned :

> ORA - 06550 - line 2, column 2 PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "SET"
>   when expecting one the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

This is what i've tried:

```
DECLARE i int
SET i = 1
WHILE i < 18000 BEGIN

INSERT INTO  Dummy 
SELECT order_id, CREATION_DATE, email, FIRST_NAME, FIX_NO, mobile_no, SECOND_NAME, SECOND_PHONE_NO, TITLE from Dummy

 SET i = i + 1
 SET order_id = order_id + 1
 END
 GO
```

Did abit of research and ended up with this :

```
 DECLARE 
i number := 1
BEGIN
 WHILE i < 18000 LOOP

i := i + 1

  INSERT INTO  Dummy
  SELECT order_id, CREATION_DATE, email, FIRST_NAME, FIX_NO, mobile_no, 
SECOND_NAME, SECOND_PHONE_NO, TITLE from 
Dummy


order_id = order_id + 1;
 END LOOP;
 END;
```

My logic here was to select the order_id and use it later to increment it, but I'm not sure it will work.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to insert 18000 rows into a table, on which every column except order_id remains the same and order_id column's value is incremented with 1 every insert.

Now I'm getting the following error :

> ORA - 06550 - line 2, column 2 PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "WHILE"
>   when expecting one the following:
>
> *_=+ at in is mod reminder not rem
>    <> or!= or ~=>=<=<> and or like like2 ...

EDIT2:

So with the help of @hotfix, the select works, and now I'm trying to concatenate a string with a number, I want order_id to be ABC + the value of OrderID that I've declared in the query, but I cant figure out how to do it.

This is what I tried : 
EDIT2.0

```
 DECLARE
  order_id1 number := 1;
  OrderID   VARCHAR2(100);
  i         number := 1;

begin

  WHILE i < 18000 LOOP

    INSERT INTO PGW_PORTAL.PGW_APPOINTMENT_INFORMATION
      SELECT OrderID,
             CREATION_DATE,
             email,
             FIRST_NAME,
             FIX_NO,
             mobile_no,
             SECOND_NAME,
             SECOND_PHONE_NO,
             TITLE

        from PGW_PORTAL.PGW_APPOINTMENT_INFORMATION;

    i := i + 1;
    OrderID := 'VO' || to_char(order_id1 + 1);

  END LOOP;
END;
```

The error message that I'm getting :

> At line 8 column 5 "VO" invalid identifier, statement ignored.

Comment: are you sure that you are using Oracle database? Looks like SQL server

Comment: It is an oracle DB, but I'm not really the best at sql, hence, still not solved the problem.

Comment: Came up with another dentative, uisng a loop, still can't get passed an error.

Comment: If your original problem has been solved but you have a new error, you should really post a new question.  Otherwise the answers to this question become nonsensical as they respond to different updates.  In any case, the reason for `"VO" invalid identifier` is that you should use single quotes to enclose a string literal, like `'VO'`.  Double quotes (usually optional) are used to enclose object or column names.

Comment: Hello, I've mentioned at the beginning that I wanted to increment the ID with 1, and then i posted my attemnt to do it, indeed i failed again, so here I am being lazy and asking for help :)). I can see that the thread is gettin pretty messy but, to respond to ur suggestion I did as u said and it returns me this error `unique constrain *some code* violaded, at line 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax of an Anonymous Block is

```
Declare
...
begin
...
end;
```

you also Forget a semicolon

```
DECLARE 

  i number := 1;
begin
  WHILE i < 18000 LOOP

    INSERT INTO  PGW_PORTAL.PGW_APPOINTMENT_INFORMATION 
      SELECT order_id, CREATION_DATE, email, FIRST_NAME, FIX_NO, mobile_no, 
             SECOND_NAME, SECOND_PHONE_NO, TITLE 
        from PGW_PORTAL.PGW_APPOINTMENT_INFORMATION ;

    i := i + 1;
    order_id := to_char(order_id) || to_char(1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

i hope you realize what you do with the Loop
you insert18000 times the data from `PGW_PORTAL.PGW_APPOINTMENT_INFORMATION`

Comment: So i've tried to run ur query but it returns : at line 12,column 7, SQL Command not properly ended and at line 7 column 5 Sql Statement ignored, and yeah i assumed it won;t increment order_id with every insert made, but atleast i wanted this to work ... and then i'd work from there

Comment: i forgot some semicolon. see my edit post

Comment: I've Edited the main post with how I've tried to concatenate the data for orderID

Comment: I've tried to do OrderID := to_char(order_id1 + 1); still no luck

Comment: read the documentation how to concatenate strings in Oracle. + is not the right Operator fo that.

Comment: Done reading, and i came up with something, but when running the statement it returns me that it can't insert null into order_id, hence what I did is probably still fault, I've concatenated like this :     OrderID := 'VO' || to_char(order_id1 + 1); ,edited the full query also